# Match String with Regex and print in java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to read a `JSON` feed (it is not JSON parsing) and detect the numbers for further manipulation. This is my trying code:

```
try {
    String regex = "^-?\\d+$";
    Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher regexMatcher = myPattern.matcher(jsonString);

    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < regexMatcher.groupCount(); i++) {
             System.out.println(regexMatcher.group(i));
        }
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

And this is the JSON string link:
http://uhunt.felix-halim.net/api/cpbook/3

I want to print only the numbers like:

100

-345

785

What is the wrong with my code? I am new in `Regex` and can't figure out the solution.

Comment: Why not use a `JSON` parser?

Comment: You should include an example of the kind of string you want to match and the output of your current code/what's going wrong with your current code.

Comment: I told at the eve of this question, it is not JSON parsing. I need to read the JSON feed and replace the number with my corresponding string and write them again in a file. Later I will parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular `JSON` you can use this:

```
String regex = ", (-?\\d+)";
```

And `regexMatcher.group(1)` will give you the number

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to provide "(" and ")" in order to create the matching groups you're looking for.

In addition to that, remove "^" and "$" since there may be more than one hit per line.

This should work:

```
try {
String regex = "(-?\\d+)";
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher regexMatcher = myPattern.matcher(jsonString);

while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < regexMatcher.groupCount(); i++) {
         System.out.println(regexMatcher.group(i));
    }
} 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use next regex:

```
"(?<=, )(-?\\d+)"
```

or

```
"(?<=,\\p{Space})(-?\d+)"
```

In this case regexMatcher.group(0) returns appropriate results.